# Could not find template file in typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am trying to call HTML file into TS file, but I see file not found error.

[image: 1]

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app/jsonData.ts',
  templateUrl: 'src/app/jsonData.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Angular';
}
```

Please explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './jsonData.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Angular';
}
```

The selector should not contain the path because the selector is going to be used like this: `<my-app></my-app>` in some HTML template/file.

And coming to the `templateUrl`, it takes relative path to the HTML template. Since both the component and the template URL you're going to use are in the same folder, you can use `./` followed by the required file name.

That being said, it is better to name your files appropriately. `app.component.ts`, `app.component.html`, `app.component.css`

Hope this helps!